# WordPress warning after update to 4.9.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I have updated the WordPress version of my site from `4.8.2` to `4.9.1` but now this [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8S0E.png) is showing up on some pages:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /app/public.built/wp-includes/media.php on line 1206

So, I have worked it out by doing this on `wp-config.php`:

```
ini_set( 'log_errors', 'On' );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 'Off' );
ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

But I imagine it does not solve the problem, only hides it.

So, someone has any idea of what might be the cause and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you show us line 1206 of `media.php` and whatever it is trying to perform `count()` on?

Comment: @rickdenhaan media.php is a core file, something custom written in theme or plugin that is triggering the issue with that function parameters